# Paypal API recurring payments

Tags: php, api, class, paypal

Working with Paypal API is the worst experience so far for me as a developer. Can anyone point me to a simplified php class to do recurring payments (yearly fee). I've been searching for one but found too many with too many differences, some say it's for recurring payments some for subscriptions. What I really need is recurring until the user cancels the membership, so no end date specified.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out

Comment: With the standard you work with forms which you submit to paypal (the whole purchase process happens there) whereas with the pro, you have an API to perform the charges behind the scenes (much more complex and requires PSI compliance but allows for a more slick interface).

Comment: I understand that with Standard only paypal users are able to pay, is this true?

Comment: They will have to create a PayPal account and then use their credit card to pay.

Comment: Then I need the pro approach. Do you know any easy to follow class I could use to implement this?

Comment: Do you know what it takes to comply with the PCI standard?? https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/getting_started.php

Comment: It's not my site, I'm only concerned implementing a payment gateway.

Comment: Your payment gateway will receive credit card information and transmit them to paypal, you need PCI certification for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this https://www.paypal.com/pdn-recurring